# How can use together Express JS with Google chart

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I developing the express application. So I want to connect it Google chart. How can do it? [I'm following this article](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart).
And also, how can change manual data to MySQL database data.

Comment: Need more info @sampath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the json data to the handlebar file in controller like this

```
res.render('handlebar_file', {db_data: mysql_data});
```

and in handlebar file you can use this data like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = {{db_data}};

        var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
      };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I am a beginner for Node JS. So please tell me what are the errors in this code section.

Comment: connection.query("SELECT * FROM tblsales", function (err, rows) {
    var chartData = [];

    if (err) throw err;

    for(var idx = 0; idx < rows.length; ++idx) {
      var item = rows[idx];
      chartData.push([item.city, item.salesQty]);
    }

    //console.log(chartData[city]);

    res.render('index', { db_data: chartData });
  });

Comment: you should use [sequelize package](http://docs.sequelizejs.com)  for making sql queries as it makes code more simple and clean

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Create an API `GET /data`using expressjs that in turn fetches data from mysql. Then utilise the API to load the **data** in google charts.

Comment: Thank you. But, I am a beginner for Node JS.Therefore, if you can be given me a sample code or article link too important for me.